# Bazel Complains about Dependencies to system header files

Tags: bazel

Our Bazel build complains as

```
ERROR: XXX/BUILD:5:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule 'YYY':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'ZZZ.c':
  '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include/stddef.h'
  '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include/stdint.h'.
```

Why does it complain about dependencies to gcc system header files?

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 with GCC 6.3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use custom crosstool? If so, can you check that those directories are covered by [cxx_builtin_include_directory](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/main/protobuf/crosstool_config.proto#L424) messages?

If you use builtin Bazel autoconfiguration, can you make sure Bazel is not using some other gcc? Bazel calls `cc -E -xc++ - -v` to find all the builtin directories, do you expect this to work? Also, Bazel checks whether `CC` environment variable is set, and if yes, it will take the compiler from there.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by cleaning up Bazels temporary files.

The reason was an upgrade of GCC during Bazel development.